# NodeJS constructing array from asynchronious callbacks before returning

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

I'm writing a function that's returning and array of values. Some of the values are calculated in a callback. But I don't know how to make the program asynchronious so all of my results are in the array, and not added after they're returned.

```
let array = [] 
for (stuff : stuffs) {
  if (condition) {
     array.add(stuff)
  } else {
     api.compute(stuff, callback(resp) {
          array.add(resp.stuff)
     }
  }
}
res.json({ "stuff": array })
```

In this example the array is written to the response before the async calls have finished.

How can I make this work asynchronously?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use one of the approaches:

- async library
- Promise.all
- coroutines/generators
- async/await

The most cool yet, I think, is `async/await`. First we modify your function, so it returns a promise:

```
const compute = function(stuff) {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    api.compute(stuff, callback(resp){
      resolve(resp.stuff)
    });
  });
};
```

Then we modify your route with async handler:

```
app.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {
  const array = [];
  for (const stuff of stuffs) {
    if (condition) {
      array.add(stuff);
    } else {
      const stuff = await compute(stuff);
      array.push(stuff);
    }
  }
  res.json({ stuff: array });
});
```

**Note:** You might need to update node version to latest.

**UPDATE:**

Those who are not awared, how event loop works, execute this snippet, and finish with that:

```
const sleep = async function(ms) {
  console.log(`Sleeping ${ms}ms`);
  return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
};

async function job() {
  console.log('start');

  for (let t = 0; t < 10; t++) {
    await sleep(100);
  }
}

job();

console.log('oops did not expect that oO');
```

You will be surprised.

Comment: This is a bad practice to put asynchronous code into a loop. You should rather create an array of promise and then `Promise.all` them. (agree async is awesome!)

Comment: It's the same as waterfall, what's so bad in it?

Comment: I agree with @GrégoryNEUT, loops should be avoided when working with asynchronious code.

Comment: Can anyone explain why it should be avoided?

Comment: @NicoVanBelle just imagine, how it's done underneath. It's the same as waterfall. How do you see bad practice here?

Comment: @NicoVanBelle First it makes your requests synchronous. Second because of the [no-await-in-loop](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-await-in-loop) rule of eslint

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT I think you used the wrong mention here

Comment: @NicoVanBelle yeah my bad^^

Comment: This doesn't work for me when I pass an async function to my API it just blocks forever.. I'm using elasticsearch.js

Comment: coroutines/generators was just an intermediate compatibility workaround and should no longer be used now that `async`/`await` is available.

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT That linting rule is rubbish. Often enough you *want* your operations to occur sequentially, especially when they depend on each other. A linter might give hints for possible optimisations, but it should not generically forbid this type of loop.

Comment: @Bergi Rules like that are useless to people that know what they are doing. It's usefull for newbies. Because 99% of time the gyu that use await in a loop is just misunderstanding async/await. In the case of this post for example there is no reason to have synchronous calls, spreading await in loops in this kinds of post is just misleading peoples that think this is the reference

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer without package using callbacks

Create a function that's gonna recursively treat all your stuffs.

```
getArray(stuffs, callback, index = 0, array = []) {
  // Did we treat all stuffs?
  if (stuffs.length >= index) {
    return callback(array);
  }

  // Treat one stuff
  if (condition) {
    array.add(stuffs[index]);

    // Call next
    return getArray(stuffs, callback, index + 1, array);
  }

  // Get a stuff asynchronously
  return api.compute(stuffs[index], (resp) => {
    array.add(resp.stuff);

    // Call next
    return getArray(stuffs, callback, index + 1, array);
  });
}
```

---

How to call it?

```
getArray(stuffs, (array) => {
   // Here you have your array
   // ...
});
```

---

**EDIT**: more explanation

---

What we want to do to transform the loop you had into a loop that handle asynchronous function call.

The purpose is that one `getArray` call gonna treat one index of your `stuffs` array.

After treating one index, the function will call itself again to treat the next index, until all get treated.

```
-> Treat index 0 -> Treat index 1 -> Treat index 2 -> Return all result
```

We are using parameters to pass the infos through the process. `Index` to know which array part we have to treat, and `array` to keep a tract of what we did calculate.

---

**EDIT**: Improvement to 100% asynchronous soluce

---

What we have done here it's a simple transposition of your initial for loop into an asynchronous code. it can be improved so by making it totally asynchronous, which make it better but slightly more difficult.

For example :

```
// Where we store the results
const array = [];

const calculationIsDone = (array) => {
  // Here our calculation is done
  // ---
};

// Function that's gonna aggregate the results coming asynchronously
// When we did gather all results, we call a function
const gatherCalculResult = (newResult) => {
  array.push(newResult);

  if (array.length === stuffs.length) {
    callback(array);
  }
};

// Function that makes the calculation for one stuff
const makeCalculation = (oneStuff) => {
  if (condition) {
    return gatherCalculResult(oneStuff);
  }

  // Get a stuff asynchronously
  return api.compute(oneStuff, (resp) => {
    gatherCalculResult(resp.stuff);
  });
};

// We trigger all calculation
stuffs.forEach(x => x.makeCalculation(x));
```

Comment: Can you explain the idea behind this? Does it work because the last return blocks ? Why not block in another way then ?